# Pyglet OpenGL bind texture

Tags: python, opengl, draw, pyglet

I am trying to bind a texture to OpenGL in Pyglet. I can't get the texture to be drawn on the quad, it just draws a white quad. I am getting the id to bind using:

```
myimage = pyglet.image.load("filename.png").get_texture()
...
def on_draw(self):
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myimage.id)
    self.planet.draw()
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

It draws it in the correct position with no texture. Here is my planet class with its verticies, texture coords, and draw function:

```
class Planet():
 def __init__(self):
    self.planet_x = 100
    self.planet_z = 100
    self.sky_height = 300

    self.setPlanet([0,0,0])
    self.planet_texcoords = [(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (0,0,1)]

 def setPlanet(self, ppos):
    self.planet_x = ppos[0] + 100
    self.planet_z = ppos[2] + 100
    self.planet_nx = ppos[0] - 100
    self.planet_nz = ppos[2] - 100
    self.sky_height = ppos[1] + 300

    self.planet_verticies = [(self.planet_nx,self.sky_height,self.planet_nz,), 
                            (self.planet_x,self.sky_height,self.planet_nz,),
                            (self.planet_x,self.sky_height,self.planet_z,),
                            (self.planet_nx,self.sky_height,self.planet_z)]
def draw(self):
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord3i(self.planet_texcoords[0][0], self.planet_texcoords[0][1], self.planet_texcoords[0][2])
    glVertex3f(self.planet_verticies[0][0], self.planet_verticies[0][1], self.planet_verticies[0][2])
    glTexCoord3i(self.planet_texcoords[1][0], self.planet_texcoords[1][1], self.planet_texcoords[1][2])
    glVertex3f(self.planet_verticies[1][0], self.planet_verticies[1][1], self.planet_verticies[1][2])
    glTexCoord3i(self.planet_texcoords[2][0], self.planet_texcoords[2][1], self.planet_texcoords[2][2])
    glVertex3f(self.planet_verticies[2][0], self.planet_verticies[2][1], self.planet_verticies[2][2])
    glTexCoord3i(self.planet_texcoords[3][0], self.planet_texcoords[3][1], self.planet_texcoords[3][2])
    glVertex3f(self.planet_verticies[3][0], self.planet_verticies[3][1], self.planet_verticies[3][2])
    glEnd()
```